# LINQ default methods for insert/delete/update are coming disabled in visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

LINQ default methods for insert/delete/update are coming disabled in visual studio 2008. The methods are grayed out (Use Runtime) and can't change to custom Stored procedures.

I am using ASP.NET MVC web application and LINQ to SQL. Any help will be apreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: Which LINQ? LINQ-to-SQL? Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean LINQ-to-SQL, you need to drag the stored procedures onto the designer surface first. Then they become editable, allowing you to select the sproc and do the mapping to parameters.

Comment: I was very frustrated by this!  Thanks for the question and answer!